# How to register multiple components in a module in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A simple way to register a component in angularjs module is to call `component` function on module passing component name and a object containing its properties (like bindings, controller etc.) as arguments.

When I have many components, I have to call `component` function repeatedly passing the above mentioned arguments.

I am not sure if its possible  but I am looking for a cleaner way to register multiple components where I dont want to write `component` function repeatedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`component` is a function, it can be called in every possible way that JavaScript allows.

```
for (const compName of ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
  app.component(compName, { templateUrl: compName + '.html', ... });
```

The need to register a lot of similar components indicates that they should be refactored to common larger components.

This also implies that components will be registered on a single module, while multiple modules and multiple files may be desirable to keep the application modular.